# Friend sent me a text and is encoded could anyone decode and tell me what it is?

Tags: cryptography

I have been searching for hours to find out what this is but I have had no luck, would anyone mind helping? We are geeks so we do this all the time but I have never seen an encoding like this "**Mlac wmstc clapwnrcb rfgq q ,rfywgp cvyar kcqqyec rm kc Kw, ksprjc uyq hsqr pgbgle rfckwfcp rsprjc**". I have no idea what to do with it and was wondering if anyone would mind decoding it.

Comment: decoding random strings is not what we do here

Comment: @schroeder: looks like that's not true - at least in this case ;-) - [answer below](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/117556/60172)

Answer (score 2):

It's ROT2, just change every letter to the second letter coming after it in the alphabet:

> Once youve encrypted this s ,thayir exact message to me My, murtle was
>   just riding themyher turtle

Comment: LOL. And here I was thinking his friend was trying to summon Cthulhu.